# How feasible is it to remove an unwanted sound from a voice clip?

Tags: editing

I'd like to remove the "growl" and the robotic voice saying "nutrient" in [this](https://files.catbox.moe/clijwn.mp3) clip. Is it doable considering I have no experience with editing audio?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. If you are OK with losing some audio quality you can hard EQ cut the low end. If you want to preserve the original audio well, there are more advanced techniques, but try EQ since you have little experience. There are also extremely good tools to isolate vocals with AI. [Adobe](https://podcast.adobe.com/enhance#) has one.

Comment: I added the link to Adobe Enhance. It actually takes two passes to clean this particular clip.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Celemony Melodyne. I'm not that familiar with it but the audio will be shown kind of like a spectrogram and you can select parts of it to delete.  Also you can look into "audio segmentation" methods.